# How can i pass form post username password into Json post

Tags: javascript, php, curl

```
$headers = array(    "Accept: application/json",    "Authorization: Bearer xxx",    "Content-Type: application/json", ); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = <<<DATA { "username":  xx; "password": xx;  "include":"LastName,FirstName,email" } DATA; curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); //for debug only! curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); $resp = curl_exec($curl); curl_close($curl); // var_dump($resp);

$decodedLocation = json_decode($resp, true); $contid = $decodedLocation["id"]; $lstname     = $decodedLocation["LastName"]; $frstname = $decodedLocation["FirstName"]; $emailid = $decodedLocation["email"]; // echo $contid ." + ". $lstname."+" .$frstname."+" .$emailid;

?>
```

the above code works perfectly but I wanted to send form username and password $signup_email and $signup_password and I been searching how could I pass dynamic variable since some hours . thanks for you time

Comment: what code are you talking about

Comment: I edited my question, its was about php json post request

Comment: Not sure but what's stopping you from replacing 'xxx' with $signup_email and the other 'xxx' with $signup_password?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to send $_POST['sign_in_email'];